# Magento custom module not working in sub store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have multiple store in magento. I created a custom module but on frontend it's url redirecting me to main store.

For example : in my custom module I have created a `testAction()` in `IndexControllers.php` so url `https: //mydomain.com/custom/index/test` working on main store but from sub store `http: //sub.mydomain.com/custom/index/test` it is redirecting to main store url. And other module working in sub store.

`testAction()` code as below :

```
public function testAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    echo 'hello';
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Please mention if you are getting any errors either in the console or inside var/log/exception.log.

Comment: No, I am not getting any error, `sub store` url return response `302 Moved Temporarily`.

Comment: I think there is problem in the multistore configuration to run on subdomains. Please go through this link http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-stores-websites-with-one-magento-installation-on-different-domains/ and check how you have configured.

Comment: But other module working in `sub store`.

Comment: try to use index.php in the url and check either the controller action is working or not.

Comment: Tried, but still redirecting me to `main store`.

Comment: I checked the same module working on my testing website, but on live where main store is running on `https` and sub store are running on  `http`, this module redirect to `main store`.

Comment: Check this link https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains. It might help. Must be issue with .htaccess file.

Comment: I followed the same article for creating `sub stores` and I have done everything which is mention in this article.

Comment: Try to add something like this 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.example\.com$`
`RewriteCond %1 !=www`
`RewriteRule ^ /user/profile/index/name/%1/`

Comment: Where? in root directory `.htaccess` or in sub domian directory `.htaccess`. and what is the work of this rule?

Comment: in the subdomain directory. It will check the domain name and force to load the controller action. Also, replace the third line to your controller URL.

Comment: Hello, I tried above rule but it is not working.